# Merge LinkedList - Why does this code caused an infinite loop?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, structure

I am attempting leetcode merging of sorted linkedlist

I have just discovered a mistake of my code that I placed `list1 = list1.next` right before the `result.next = list1`, causing the code to caused an infinite loop. However, I tried to trace and still don't understand how the logic caused an infinite loop.

**Wrong Solution**

```
    // Loop until list1 and list2 is not empty
    while (list1 != null && list2 != null) {
        if (list1.val < list2.val) {
            list1 = list1.next;
            result.next = list1;
            
        } else {
            list2 = list2.next;
            result.next = list2;
            
        }

        System.out.println(list2.val);

        result = result.next;

    }
```

**Correct Solution**

```
    while (list1 != null && list2 != null) {
        if (list1.val < list2.val) {
            
            result.next = list1;
            list1 = list1.next;
            
        } else {
            
            result.next = list2;
            list2 = list2.next;
            
        }

        System.out.println(list2.val);

        result = result.next;

    }
```

Can someone enlighten me why does the placement of list1 = list1.next and list2 = list2.next, will caused an infinite loop? Here are my debugging attempts

[image: 1) The 2nd last iteration]

[image: The final iteration]

As you can see the two images, represents the value of the result linkedlist, which will continuously loop through the value of 4,2,3 -> 2,4,2 -> 4,2,3 -> 2,4,2 .... vice versa.

Finally here is my input
1,2,4
1,3,4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you draw the states of your list nodes on a piece of paper step by step, you'll see how that cycle gets introduced.

Here is a visualisation -- step by step. I assume the code has first created a dummy node to which also `result` has a reference. Before the loop gets executed we thus have this state:

```
list1
  ↓ 
┌───┐   ┌───┐   ┌───┐
│ 1 ├──►│ 2 ├──►│ 4 ├──► null
└───┘   └───┘   └───┘

list2
  ↓ 
┌───┐   ┌───┐   ┌───┐
│ 1 ├──►│ 3 ├──►│ 4 ├──► null
└───┘   └───┘   └───┘

result
  ↓ 
┌───┐
│   ├──► null
└───┘
  ↑
dummy
```

**Iteration 1** of the loop: `if` condition is false, so `list2` is moved, and then `result->next` gets the same reference, and then `result` itself moves:

```
list1
  ↓ 
┌───┐   ┌───┐   ┌───┐
│ 1 ├──►│ 2 ├──►│ 4 ├──► null
└───┘   └───┘   └───┘

        list2
          ↓ 
┌───┐   ┌───┐   ┌───┐
│ 1 ├──►│ 3 ├──►│ 4 ├──► null
└───┘┌─►└───┘   └───┘
     │    ↑
┌───┐│  result
│   ├┘
└───┘
  ↑
dummy
```

**Iteration 2** of the loop: `if` condition is true, so `list1` is moved, and then `result->next` gets the same reference, and then `result` itself moves:

```
        list1
          ↓ 
┌───┐   ┌───┐   ┌───┐
│ 1 ├──►│ 2 ├──►│ 4 ├──► null
└───┘┌─►└───┘   └───┘
     │    ↑
     │  result
     └───────┐
        list2│
          ↓  │
┌───┐   ┌───┐│  ┌───┐
│ 1 ├──►│ 3 ├┘  │ 4 ├──► null
└───┘┌─►└───┘   └───┘
     │    
┌───┐│
│   ├┘
└───┘
  ↑
dummy
```

At this point we already have a serious problem, as the last node that belonged to the second list has now become detached and unreachable.

**Iteration 3** of the loop: `if` condition is true, so `list1` is moved, and then `result->next` gets the same reference (but this was already the case), and then `result` itself moves:

```
                list1
                  ↓ 
┌───┐   ┌───┐   ┌───┐
│ 1 ├──►│ 2 ├──►│ 4 ├──► null
└───┘┌─►└───┘   └───┘
     │            ↑
     │          result
     └───────┐
        list2│
          ↓  │
┌───┐   ┌───┐│  ┌───┐
│ 1 ├──►│ 3 ├┘  │ 4 ├──► null
└───┘┌─►└───┘   └───┘
     │    
┌───┐│
│   ├┘
└───┘
  ↑
dummy
```

**Iteration 4** of the loop: `if` condition is false, so `list2` is moved (and is going the wrong way!), and then `result->next` gets the same reference (creating the cycle!), and then `result` itself moves:

```
        list2   list1
          ↓       ↓ 
     ┌───────────────┐
┌───┐└─►┌───┐   ┌───┐│
│ 1 ├──►│ 2 ├──►│ 4 ├┘
└───┘┌─►└───┘   └───┘
     │    ↑
     │  result
     └───────┐
┌───┐   ┌───┐│  ┌───┐
│ 1 ├──►│ 3 ├┘  │ 4 ├──► null
└───┘┌─►└───┘   └───┘
     │    
┌───┐│
│   ├┘
└───┘
  ↑
dummy
```

And now the cycle has been made! The node with value 2 points to the node with value 4, and vice versa!

Comment: Thank you. Now i understand clearly. I was confused because of the reference point.

Answer (score 0):

Need to see all the relevent code file before answering,but i observe that you are doing

```
System.out.println(list2.val);
```

You are assuming list2!=null here

```
while (list1 != null && list2 != null)
```

but in the code you are doing

```
list2 = list2.next;
            
        }

        System.out.println(list2.val);
```

what if list2 becomes null here .Need to put null checks

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the next pointer of the result node to the next node of the list1 or list2 node. You are setting it to the list1 or list2 node itself. So you are creating a cycle in the linked list. You need to set the next pointer of the result node to the next node of the list1 or list2 node. So the correct code should be:

```
result.next = list1.next;
list1 = list1.next;

result.next = list2.next;
list2 = list2.next;
```